# How do I split my one document into many at page breaks in VBA?

Tags: vba, split, ms-word, page-break

I am new to VBA. I got this macro from online and it has worked for me before, but now I am getting a runtime error from it.

The macro is supposed to take a mail merged document I have, and split it into individual documents for each recipient.

The runtime error 5487 is pointing me to the line

```
" .SaveAs fileName:=StrTxt &...".
```

I have tried to save it as a different file format, and have gone through the other posts on StackOverflow where others have the same error, but I am still getting the error message.

My code is:

```
Sub SplitMergedDocument()
  ' Source: http://msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
  Const StrNoChr As String = """*./\:?|"
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, StrTxt As String
  Dim Rng As Range, Doc As Document, HdFt As HeaderFooter
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  j = InputBox("How many Section breaks are there per record?", "Split By Sections ", 1)
  With ActiveDocument
      For i = 1 To .Sections.Count - 1 Step j ' Process each Section
          With .Sections(i)
              Set Rng = .Range.Paragraphs(1).Range ' Get 1st paragraph
              With Rng
                  .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1 'range to exclude final paragraph break
                  StrTxt = .Text
                  For k = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
                      StrTxt = Replace(StrTxt, Mid(StrNoChr, k, 1), "_")
                  Next
              End With
              ' Construct destination file path & name
              StrTxt = ActiveDocument.Path & Application.PathSeparator & StrTxt
              Set Rng = .Range ' Get whole Section
              With Rng
                  If j > 1 Then .MoveEnd wdSection, j - 1
                  .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1 'Contract range to exclude Section break
                  .Copy ' Copy range
              End With
          End With
          ' Create output document
          Set Doc = Documents.Add(Template:=ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.FullName _
              , Visible:=False)
          With Doc
              ' Paste contents into output document, preserving formatting
              .Range.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting)
              ' Delete trailing paragraph breaks & page breaks at end
              While .Characters.Last.Previous = vbCr Or .Characters.Last.Previous = Chr(12)
                  .Characters.Last.Previous = vbNullString
              Wend
              For Each HdFt In Rng.Sections(j).Headers ' Replicate headers & footers
                  .Sections(j).Headers(HdFt.Index).Range.FormattedText = HdFt.Range.FormattedText
              Next
              For Each HdFt In Rng.Sections(j).Footers
                  .Sections(j).Footers(HdFt.Index).Range.FormattedText = HdFt.Range.FormattedText
              Next
              ' Save & close output document
              .SaveAs FileName:=StrTxt & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument _
                    , AddToRecentFiles:=False
              .Close SaveChanges:=False
          End With
      Next
  End With
  Set Rng = Nothing: Set Doc = Nothing
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why the interest in sections and "records"?  Are you splitting by page breaks or not?

Comment: There is nothing 'wrong' with the macro; it works as intended, *provided* the document you're running it on has already been saved. Note also that the code splits the document a *Section* breaks, not at *Page* breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more (such as the value of `StrTxt`), I can't say for sure *why* you're getting the error but it's likely either an invalid filename, or the file is locked by another process, or a permissions issue.

Perhaps the procedure below will work better for you.  (I'm unclear on the significance of "records" in your code.)

---

## Split document into separate files for each page:

This procedure splits the `ActiveDocument` into one `.DOCX` file per "visible page" (calculated page breaks, manual page breaks, section breaks, etc).\

```
Sub WordDocToPages()
'splits active Word doc by page into separate DOCX files (same folder as active doc)
  Dim doc As Document, docPage As Document, rgPage As Range
  Dim pgNum As Long, pgCnt As Long, ext As String, fName As String
  Set doc = ActiveDocument                                        'Use current document
  Set rgPage = doc.Range                                          'create range of 1 page
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False                              'prevent screen updates
  pgCnt = doc.Content.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)      'get page count
  Do While pgNum < pgCnt
      pgNum = pgNum + 1                                           'increment page counter
      Application.StatusBar = "Saving page " & pgNum & " of " & pgCnt
      If pgNum < pgCnt Then
          Selection.GoTo wdGoToPage, wdGoToAbsolute, pgNum + 1    'top of next page
          rgPage.End = Selection.Start                            'end of page=top of next
      Else
          rgPage.End = doc.Range.End                              'end of last page=EOF
      End If
      rgPage.Copy                                                 'copy page
      Set docPage = Documents.Add(Visible:=False)                 'create new document
      With docPage
          With .Range
              .Paste 'paste page
              .Find.Execute Findtext:="^m", ReplaceWith:=""       'remove manual breaks
              .Select
          End With
          With Selection
              .EndKey wdStory                                     'goto end of doc
              .MoveLeft wdCharacter, 1, wdExtend                  'remove final CR
              If Asc(.Text) = 13 Then .Delete wdCharacter, 1      'remove trailing CR
          End With
          ext = Mid(doc.FullName, InStrRev(doc.FullName, "."))    'extract file extension
          fName = Replace(doc.FullName, ext, " #" & _
              Format(pgNum, String(Len(CStr(pgCnt)), "0")) & ".docx") 'new filename
          .SaveAs fName, wdFormatDocumentDefault                  'save single-page doc
          .Close                                                  'close new document
      End With
      rgPage.Collapse wdCollapseEnd                               'ready for next page
  Loop

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True                               'resume screen updates
  Application.StatusBar = "Document was split into " & pgNum & " files."
  Set docPage = Nothing: Set rgPage = Nothing: Set doc = Nothing  'cleanup objects
End Sub
```

<sup>This is loosely based on the example at [Usefulware Sharing](https://usefulwarecom.wordpress.com/do-you-know-how-to-split-a-massive-document-into-multiple-documents-in-word/).</sup>

The new files are saved to the same folder as `ActiveDocument.Path`, with the document title appended with a sequential number. Note that **existing output files are overwritten**, and there is no validation or error handling.